# BizTalk 2016 Oracle.DataAcces 4.121.1.0 not found, 2.112.4.0 installed

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

We recently changed to a new BizTalk version from 2010. We are trying to configure our first ReceivePort on it, but we are running into the error that seems to indicate that the version of the Oracle.DataAcces that is in the cache is very outdated.

I have been looking around but unfortunately, i am not an expert in how the GAC works so i haven't figured out how BizTalk selects which version to search for.

Would the solution be to Install a newer version of the Oracle Dataacces into the GAC? And is the Oracle Data adapter part of the BizTalk adapter pack? That Pack was pre installed on our server so it would be weird if it was the cause of the wrong version.

Edit: The ODAC we installed claims to be the version 4 one (in the read me and download link) but doesn't seem to be the one in the cache.

Comment: The Oracle client is a royal pain in the butt to set up. It doesn't play nicely if you try to install multiple versions on the same machine, and it never seems to GAC everything you'd think it would. Make sure you have the .NET 4.x one GACed - if you have the requisite DLLs, you could just GAC them using gacutil from a developer command prompt.

Comment: @DanField We will have to give that a try. Our Live server doesn't have Visual Studio though and isn't gacutil part of visual studio? or can i just place it on the Live server without Visual studio?

Comment: GacUtil is part of the Windows SDK.  If your server doesn't hav the SDK installed, you can GAC using powershell like here: https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/12/16/using-powershell-to-install-a-dll-into-the-gac/

Comment: @Andy Use gacutil by copying it from a dev box (gacutil.exe and gacutil.exe.config) to your server. Then, use it to install the wanted DLL to the GAC by using the "/i" switch.

Answer (score 0):

You MUST install Microsoft BizTalk Adapter for Enterprise Application. if you are using the same box that you used for BTS 2010, then Uninstall, the Old Adapter pack, and install the new one from BTS Media.

[image]

Comment: All of these have Green ticks with them unfortunatly.